# Ajax call go to error but saving is ok on the server side

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I use spring boot 2.
I do a ajax call to save form.

```
$("#factoriesForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    var factoriesId = $('#factoriesForm input[name="id"]').val();

    var form = transForm.serialize('#factoriesForm');
    form = JSON.stringify(form);

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/template/edit/factories/" + factoriesId,
        data: form,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#factoriesForm input[name="id"]').val(data.id);

            new PNotify({
                title: /*[[#{success.title}]]*/ ,
                text: /*[[#{success.msg}]]*/ ,
                type: 'error',
                styling: 'bootstrap3',
                delay: 4000
            });

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            new PNotify({
                title: /*[[#{error.title}]]*/ ,
                text: /*[[#{error.msg}]]*/ ,
                type: 'success',
                styling: 'bootstrap3',
                delay: 4000
            });

        }
    });

});
```

In spring my condroller do

```
@PostMapping("template/edit/factories/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<FactoriesDto> edit(Model model, @RequestBody FactoriesDto dto, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(factoriesFacace.save(dto), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Saving is done correctly, but when I debug in js that code in error section instead of success.

> Unexpected end of JSON input" stack : "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of
>   JSON input↵    at parse ()↵    at Ut
>   (http://localhost:8080/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js:2:73768)↵
>   at k
>   (http://localhost:8080/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js:2:77335)↵
>   at XMLHttpRequest.
>   (http://localhost:8080/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js:2:79907)"

status code is 200.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Spring controller in:

```
@PostMapping("template/edit/factories/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<FactoriesDto> edit(Model model, @RequestBody FactoriesDto dto, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    factoriesFacace.save(dto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Try to return a JsonObject type ( return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(entities, HttpStatus.OK); ) where "entities" is a JSONObject variable.